# How I can provide an api url to my library that is run via the browser once I build and minify it with webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a JavaScript project that builds a widget used by third party websites and consumes my API. The library is configured by a JavaScript file names `config.js`:

```
api_url="https://example.com";

module.exports={
  'api_url': api_url
};
```

What I want is ton replace the `api_url` depending on my build environment with the appropriate URL. Do you have any idea how to do this?

If I use the `env.NODE_ENV` or environmental variables, will be accessible only if the JavaScript is executed by Nodejs. Therefore, for browser-build JS is a no-go for me. I want to be able to build my JavaScript with values that will be hard-coded depending on the environment into the appropriate variables.

What I trully need is my my API to be build for browser executed javascript.

Answer (score 0):

A good approach is for the `config.js` to be aqutogenerated via webpack or gulp.  In my case I use the gulp tool to autogenerate mine. The gulp access the appropriate environmental variables from the pipeline's environmental variable and fills the appropriate values into config.js:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var webpack = require('webpack-stream');

gulp.task('build',function(){
   const url !!process.env.API_URL?process.env.API_URL:'http://example.com';
   const environmentString=`/* Generated at ${Date.now().toString()} */\nmodule.exports = { api_url:"${url}" };`
   fs.writeFileSync('./config.js',environmentString);

   // Rest of build here
});
```

Similar approach can be used in case that webpack is used as well. In case that `config.js` calculates some configuration fields (for example a url such as SENTRY DSN) just create an another javascript file named `environment.js` and fill with just the environmental variables.